# Remove arrows from form element select in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to remove the up/down arrows that show up next to the clock icon on right. Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Date:</label>
    <div class="right-inner-addon ">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
        <select class="form-control input-lg">
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

After applying the suggest css change below this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this using the `appearance` property:

The `appearance` property allows you to make an element look like a standard user interface element.

```
select.form-control {
  -moz-appearance: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: It worked but now the selected item is half cut off. Posted a picture in the original thread.

Comment: You can adjust with  padding and margin or even with line-height