# How to remove input-group <select> arrow in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, html-select

**How can i remove that horrible looking double arrow in select ?** 
Any other answears about this article that i found doesn't work.

```html
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Date</label>
      <div class"row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <input.....>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7">
          <div class="input-group">
            <select class="custom-select">
              <option.....>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Image:

[image]

I tried those solutions:

- [How to remove the arrow in dropdown in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576503/how-to-remove-the-arrow-in-dropdown-in-bootstrap-4)
- [Remove arrows from form element select in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038951/remove-arrows-from-form-element-select-in-bootstrap-3)
- [Select removing dropdown arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow)
- [How to replace arrow dropdown select in boostrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782201/how-to-replace-arrow-dropdown-select-in-boostrap)
- [Change color and appearance of drop down arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow)

but not works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the arrows, you should force apply background style for your `custom-select` class as those arrows are set as background. Try the below code as reference.

```css
.custom-select{
background: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Date</label>
      <div class"row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <input.....>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7">
          <div class="input-group">
            <select class="custom-select">
              <option.....>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answear. I didn't even know that those arrows are select's background. Your solution works.

Comment: Glad it helped. Accept it as answer so that it can help others.

Comment: background: none will remove the color also. use background-image: none; so that it doesn't reflect the background-color.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.custom-select {
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change css to:

```
.custom-select{
   background:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, better off using background-image: none.  I've added fields so you can see the effects.

Ensure you adjust the padding to reduce the whitespace that was allocated for the dropdown arrows, otherwise the text will clip in seemingly empty space.

```css
.custom-select{
background-image: none !important;
padding-left: 10px !important;
padding-right: 10px !important;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Date</label>
      <div class"row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" placeholder="some text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
          <div class="input-group">
            <select class="custom-select">
              <option>Sample text</option>
              <option>Second text</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```